# python problems reading correctly a nested JSON file

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I'm having trouble reading correctly a nested JSON file into a dataframe. This a sample of the json file with pharmaceutical products I'm working on:

```
[
    [
        {
            "ScrapingOriginIdentifier": "N",
            "ActiveSubstances": [
                "A.C.T.H. pour préparations homéopathiques"
            ],
            "ATC": null,
            "Name": "A.C.T.H. BOIRON, degré de dilution compris entre 4CH et 30CH ou entre 8DH et 60DH",
            "OtherFields": [
                {
                    "Name": null,
                    "Value": "CIS: 6 499 638 6",
                    "Type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "Name": null,
                    "Value": "MA Holder since: 06/10/2021",
                    "Type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "Package": "1 tube de 4 g de granules",
            "PharmaceuticalForm": "Granules",
        },
        {
            "ScrapingOriginIdentifier": "N",
            "ActiveSubstances": [
                "A.C.T.H. pour préparations homéopathiques"
            ],
            "ATC": null,
            "Name": "A.C.T.H. BOIRON, degré de dilution compris entre 4CH et 30CH ou entre 8DH et 60DH",
            "OtherFields": [
                {
                    "Name": null,
                    "Value": "CIS: 6 499 638 6",
                    "Type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "Name": null,
                    "Value": "MA Holder since: 06/10/2021",
                    "Type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "Package": "1 tube de 20 g de pommade",
            "PharmaceuticalForm": "Granules",
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "ScrapingOriginIdentifier": "34009 341 687 6 5",
            "ActiveSubstances": [],
            "ATC": null,
            "Name": "17 B ESTRADIOL BESINS-ISCOVESCO 0,06 POUR CENT, gel pour application cutanée en tube",
            "OtherFields": [
                {
                    "Name": null,
                    "Value": "CIS: 6 858 620 3",
                    "Type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "Name": null,
                    "Value": "Codes: 34009 341 687 6 5 or 341 687-6",
                    "Type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "Package": "1 tube(s) aluminium verni de 80 g avec applicateur polystyrène",
            "PharmaceuticalForm": "Gel",
        }
    ]
]
```

I can see the problem is that it's nested by `ScrapingOriginIdentifier`. I read the file using:

`dataset = pd.read_json('data.json', orient='records')`

And tried to 'shape' it correctly using:

`dataset = pd.json_normalize(dataset)`

This still did not work. How can I read the file correctly in order to get all?

Comment: Try removing trailing commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it contains unquoted values **null**, which should be **"null"**. Then, the structure of your json is not suitable for creating a dataframe.
The structure is the following:

```
[
  [
   { "ScrapingOriginIdentifier": "...", ...},
   { "ScrapingOriginIdentifier": "...", ...},
  ],
  [
   { "ScrapingOriginIdentifier": "...", ...},
  ]
]
```

While it *should* be constructed like this:

```
[
  [
   { "ScrapingOriginIdentifier": "...", ...},
  ],
  [
   { "ScrapingOriginIdentifier": "...", ...},
  ],
  [
   { "ScrapingOriginIdentifier": "...", ...},
  ]
]
```

Please consider restructuring your list this way:

```py
json = your_json
new_list = []
for list in json:
    for item in list:
        new_list.append(item)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_list)
```

Comment: Yeah the biggest problem was the structure of the json, I managed to manipulate it from the origin. Thank you!